# How to get controller instance from actionResult

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing some extension methods over `ActionResult` to be called as chain while call `View(model)`, `Redirect(url)`, etc. However I need to access the current controller instance to add some data to Model, ViewBag, ViewData, etc.

Anyone has a way to get Current `Controller` Instance from `ActionResult`

Comment: Did you really mean from `ActionResult` or did you mean from `ActionContext`? IT should be obvious why you defo cannot get to the controller from a result, but from the current action context its totally possible.

Answer (score 0):

It was not intended to have `Controller` or `ControllerContext` because `ControllerContext` is passed to `ExecuteResult` when it is time to execute the result. So there is no way you can get it in generic way.